# What am I told here about the use of 「所々」

Tags: reading-comprehension

The following is an excerpt from a dialogue between and my language partner. I asked her about the use of ところどころ and wether particles need to be attached at the end or not. For context, this is the full block in which she replied to me concerning this topic:

> 「所々（ところどころ）」の使い方です。 これが意外と難しいです。助詞がつく場合とつかない場合があるのです。 「所々」は「あちこち」を意味する名詞ですが、それ自体で副詞のようにも使えます（in places) 「所々、原作と違ってもいい」 は正しい使い方です。 「所々に、原作と違う部分がある」 も正しい使い方です。 「所々で違う場面展開がある」 のように使うこともできます。
>
> 使い分けを説明するのは難しいのですが、基本的に「所々」だけで使える場合が多いように思います。 上の３つの文章はすべて「所々」だけでも使えますが、「所々に、原作と違ってもいい」 という言い方はできず、「所々で、原作と違ってもいい」 という言い方はできます。 つまり、助詞を使うことで意味を限定しているのではないでしょうか。 わかりにくかったらごめんなさい。

The sentence in question:
上の３つの文章はすべて「所々」だけでも使えますが、「所々に、原作と違ってもいい」 という言い方はできず、「所々で、原作と違ってもいい」 という言い方はできます

My attempt at translation:
"Concerning the 3 sentences from above, although with only 所々　is entirely usable, not using the 「所々に、原作と違ってもいい」way of saying, you can use this way of saying 「所々で、原作と違ってもいい」."

As I understood and translated the sentence, she is telling me that I can ALWAYS use 所々 without any particle attached, but if I want to attach a particle, I can always use で instead of に?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sentence is simpler than you might think. It's just a compound sentence made of three independent clauses, each of which has its own topic (marked with は). You can split it into three sentences.

1. 上の３つの文章**は**すべて「所々」だけでも使えます。
   For all three sentences above, you can just use 所々 (without に/で).
2. が、「所々に、原作と違ってもいい」 という言い方**は**できません。
   However, saying 「所々に、原作と違ってもいい」 is not valid.
3. 「所々で、原作と違ってもいい」 という言い方**は**できます。
   Saying 「所々で、原作と違ってもいい」 is okay.

---

As she said, 所々 is both a standalone adverb and a noun that takes で/に/から/etc. See [other questions for the difference between で and に](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%E3%81%AB-and-%E3%81%A7?sort=votes&pageSize=50).